# C# Generic parameter from a string variable

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, attributes

I have two classes, Customer and Country.   Customer has a property called HomeCountry, which i have decorated with a custom attribute called "Lookup" and takes a string parameter "Country".  The purpose is, when I am using the Customer class, the item in HomeCountry must exist in the Country class (which happens to be a list).

I am using reflection to iterate the Customer class, it finds the attribute and i want it to check the value in the list of country items.  So far I have:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo _pi in object.GetType().GetProperties()) {
  IEnumerable<Attribute> _attrs = _pi.GetCustomAttributes();
  foreach (Attribute _a in _attrs) {
    Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(_type, null);
    // what goes here?
  }
}
```

I have a method:

```
public T Populate<T>(params string[] _parameters)
```

I think i want to do

```
List<obj> v = populate<obj>();
```

or

```
List<typeof(obj)> v = populate<typeof(obj)>();
```

but obviously nothing works!  Can anybody help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Consider using enum for your countries that will allow you not to do that kind of code with reflection. You are doing a simple thing in a very complex way.

Comment: I'm not sure which component of Your code actually contains the list You mentioned. Please provide an example how You would like to use those classes.

Comment: If you go the enum route, make sure to properly validate the input. Any natural number will parse to an enum (assuming it fits the inherited number type).

Comment: This whole thing looks like a misuse of reflection. Please provide code for `Country` and `Customer` classes and the context of the validation.

Comment: I was trying to make an example that made sense... the objects are populated from a source database (which i have no control over).  The populate<obj> currently takes a parameter which is the primary key and reads the item from the source database then returns the populated object.  What i was trying to make work here is if one table on the database is a lookup value from another table, i wanted to use an attribute to mark that relationship, and then before i try and write this object to the database, check that the lookup is legitimate before performing the database write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hunting around, this is the answer i was looking for...

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(class).GetMethod("Populate");
method = method.MakeGenericMethod(p.PropertyType);
_val = method.Invoke(class, new object[] { _prms });
```

I guess my issue was i was asking the wrong question!

Answer (score 0):

OK i will try and provide a full example:

I have a CUSTOMER_ORDER class:

```
public class CUSTOMER_ORDER {
  public CUSTOMER_ORDER() {}

  [Key(0)]
  public string OrderNumber {get;set;}
  public MPCCOM_SHIP_VIA ShipVia {get;set;}
}
```

Then the MPCCOM_SHIP_VIA class:

```
public class MPCCOM_SHIP_VIA {
  public MPCCOM_SHIP_VIA() {}

  [Key(0)]
  public string ID {get;set;}
  public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

I have a method called Populate< T > which takes a class and then uses reflection to loop all the properties and build a select statement, executes it, and then returns the data and populates the object:

```
public T Populate<T>(params string[] @Parameters)
        {
            Type _t = typeof(T);
            dynamic _o = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), null);

            SqlBuilder _sb = new SqlBuilder();
            _sb.Table = string.Format("{0}.{1}", _Owner, _t.Name.ToString());
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in _t.GetProperties(Utilities.BindingFlags))
            {
                if (p.GetMethod.IsPrivate == false) _sb.Fields.Add(p.Name.ToString());
                IEnumerable<Attribute> _attrs = p.GetCustomAttributes();
                foreach (Attribute _a in _attrs)
                {
                    if (_a.TypeId.ToString().Equals(typeof(Key).FullName))
                    {
                        int _position = ((Key)_a).Position;
                        try
                        {
                            string _parameter = @Parameters[_position];
                            _sb.Where.Add(string.Format("{0} = '{1}'", p.Name, _parameter));
                        }
                        catch {}
                    }
                }
            }

            using (OleDbCommand _cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                _cmd.Connection = this._cn;
                _cmd.CommandText = _sb.SQL;
                if (_trn != null) _cmd.Transaction = _trn;
                _cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                using (OleDbDataReader _reader = _cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (_reader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < _reader.FieldCount; x++)
                        {
                            foreach (PropertyInfo p in _t.GetProperties(Utilities.BindingFlags))
                            {

                                if (p.GetMethod.IsPrivate == false)
                                {
                                    if (p.Name.Equals(_reader.GetName(x).ToString()))
                                    {
                                        dynamic _val = _reader.GetValue(x);
                                        if (p.ReflectedType.BaseType.Name.Equals(""))
                                        {
                                            // what goes here!

                                        }
                                        try
                                        {
                                            p.GetSetMethod(true).Invoke(_o, new object[] { _val });
                                        }
                                        catch { }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new DatabaseObjectNotFound(_t.Name.ToString(), string.Join(",",@Parameters));
                    }
                }
            }
            return (T)_o;

        }
```

So, as i read an order, the source DB gets the key to the MPCCOM_SHIP_VIA in the respective field, i want to call the same Populate method against the MPCCOM_SHIP_VIA object with the key.  I hope this makes more sense demonstrating what i want to do.  And thanks

Comment: Oh sorry realized afterwards, my first approach was to have an attribute in the customer order class against ShipVia [Lookup("MPCCOM_SHIP_VIA")] but realised afterwards that i could just set the type and save myself some work!